# Falling at the centre of the Earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, planets

Let’s assume to drill a hole at Earth surface at the point P1. The hole passes throughout the centre of the Earth and finishes at the opposite side at the point P2. Let’s assume then that 1) Earth does not rotate and 2) to make vacuum inside this hole.

If I leave an object falling at the point P1, it is said that it will gain velocity falling down to the centre of the Earth. At the centre of the Earth it will have the maximum kinetic energy and the minimum potential energy. After passing the centre of the Earth, the object will continue its run pointing to point2, but progressively loosing its kinetic energy, that will become 0 at P2. Then, it will fall again towards the centre of the Earth again and again.

In this scenario only the component directed towards the centre of the Earth ($z$-direction) is considered for gravity. What about the components along the perpendicular $xy$-plane? What I mean: when the object is at, let’s say, 1500 km below the Earth surface, there will be a relevant gravity all around in the $xy$ plane. These components will delete each other and don’t affect the object trajectory, but do they play some other role or is it like they are totally absent? Do they somehow affect the energy of the object (and its velocity)?

PS: let’s assume the Earth if perfectly homogenous and spherical

PPS: I see that similar questions have been already answered, but my specific question is: do the components in the xy-plane play some (even minimal) role or not?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Comment: If your idealized earth has a uniform density, then this is a simple harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but may be I was not too brave in my question to explain what I really meant when I cited "the components in the xy-plane". I'm not an expert at all in this field, but I was wandering if gravitational waves could play some role (at least in principle, independently on their magnitude). I'm not a fan of Wikipedia, but I read that "gravitational waves are radiated by objects whose motion involves acceleration". So, does an object as described in my question radiate infinitesimally amounts of these waves and loose energy?

Answer (score 1):

In the setting that you describe, the x and y components have no overall effect at all.

If you have multiple forces acting upon a (point) body, the result is exactly the same that a single force would have, if the single force is the vector sum of all the individual forces.

As your hole goes through the center of Earth, the mass distribution around this hole is perfectly symmetric in the xy plane, so all gravity force components along x or y will be compensated by opposite ones. The only asymmetry with regard to the falling object is in the z direction, so here the different gravity forces add up to something that is zero only at the center of Earth. And vector math tells us that, for the addition of vectors, we can treat the x, y, and z components individually, so whatever happens in x or y has no influence on z.